# Sequelize: How to find all rows where amount of likes are equal to 2

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I Have the next attempt to do that, but is says, that "likesAmount" column doesn't exists. What should I do?

```
 let pictures = await models.Picture.findAll({
  attributes: {
    include: [
      [sequelize.literal('(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "pictureLikes" WHERE "pictureLikes"."pictureId"=picture.id)'), 'likesAmount'],
      [sequelize.literal('(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM comments WHERE comments."pictureId"=picture.id)'), 'commentsAmount']
    ]
  },
  where:{likesAmount: 2} ,
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use this literal in the `where` option like this:

```js
where: Sequelize.where(sequelize.literal('(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "pictureLikes" WHERE "pictureLikes"."pictureId"=picture.id)'), Op.eq, '2');
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but there is one more question. Is it possible to add more than one query in such where option? Like standard: where:{id: 3}, for example

Comment: Yes, you can combine several `Sequelize.where` in `Op.and` or `Op.or`